# Display form fields if radio button is selected on page load or on click

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I am trying to get specific form fields to show if a particular radio button is selected on page load OR if it is clicked on.  I've been messing with this for a few hours and this is the closest that I have gotten.  Right now it's running the entire showForm function no matter what. I switched out `input[type='radio']` with `$(this)` but `$(this)` means nothing so that obviously didn't work ([here's the JS fiddle for that.](http://jsfiddle.net/kkyow7a1/16/)  The form works with it on click but not the displaying of the form on page load).  I also took all of this out of the `showForm` function and tried to `trigger.click()`like this

```
if ($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked')){
    $(this).trigger('click');       
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".currentForm, .address, .trust, .individual").hide();

if ($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked')){
    showForm();     
}

 $("input[type='radio']").click(showForm);    

function showForm(){    
    if($("input[type='radio']").attr('name') == 'enterAddress' && $(this).attr('value') == 'true') {
        $('.address').slideDown( "slow", function() {});                   
    }       
    else{
        $('.address').slideUp( "slow", function() {});  
    }

    //Individual
    if($("input[type='radio']").attr('id') == 'nameType1') {
        $('.currentForm, .address, .trust, .business').hide();  
        $('.individual, .currentForm').slideDown( "slow", function() {});  
        $('#enterAddress1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#enterAddress2').attr('checked', true);                
    } 
    //Trust
    else if($("input[type='radio']").attr('id') == 'nameType2'){
        $('.currentForm, .address, .individual, .business').hide();
        $('.trust, .currentForm').slideDown( "slow", function() {});
        $('#enterAddress1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#enterAddress2').attr('checked', true);
    }
    //Business
    else if($("input[type='radio']").attr('id') == 'nameType3'){
        $('.currentForm, .address, .individual, .trust').hide();
        $('.business, .currentForm').slideDown( "slow", function() {});
        $('#enterAddress1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#enterAddress2').attr('checked', true);
    }
}// end showForm                
});
```

[Here is the current jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkyow7a1/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following instead:

```
$("input[type='radio']").on('change', showForm).filter(':checked').change();

//assuming you have just one radio button
//if not then make ':checked' be specific to that particular radio button.
```

And you wont need this part:

```
if ($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked')){
    showForm();     
}
```